# Virtual credit cards - what info is passed? How and what can I store?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, payment-processing, fraud-prevention

There are a lot of VCC issuers out there, and majority of them only give you 3 things:

The card number

CVV code

Expiry date

Do they give out any other info other than that, like your first name, last name, address, country (some of the card issuers require this info)? Is there a tool/service to check what info is passed if I enter card details? A lot of people mention maxmind.

Is it possible to code something (or find a 3rd party service) that answers my question?

Comment: What do you mean "they only give you" ? When you call an API or something different?

Comment: No, when you purchase an virtual credit card from a supplier, or ask your bank/payment service for a virtual card. Most of the time they only give you something like this: PAN: 46651626122 CVV: 123 EXP: 2020-01-31, and only few of them ask you to input your name and address. I want to know, whether I can somehow simulate or make an actual payment and see what info from my VCC was passed to the merchant. Why only some of them require a name and address? Can the merchant see my name and address if I purchase something with my VCC, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I've yet to use one. But why would your supplier or bank give you your own details back?

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language, maybe I'm not expressing myself clearly enough. I want to find out how anonymous these virtual cards are, I'm looking for a service or a way to build something myself, where I could simulate or pay for something with my virtual credit card and see whether my name and address was sent to the service provider. I want to learn why only some of the providers require name and address, maybe they keep this info only for themselves and name/address is not actually required for successful payment.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience working with various payment gateways, someone taking payment (an online store, for example) does not receive any address information back when they take payment using any kind of credit card. They will make an API call, to try and take payment, passing to the payment gateway information the user has typed in (credit card number, expiry card, address maybe...) and they will get back authorisation or failure. Failure may include reasons like 'Address did not match' but they will not send back the address they have on record.

Requiring a user to enter more details which the credit card company can validate makes the transaction less likely to be fraudulent, but also makes it more likely to be uncompleted, either because it fails for some reason or because the user is interrupted, is impatient, etc.

For this reason, it isn't always compulsory to put in an address but this is likely reflected in the cost to the online store (or the amount of chargebacks that they suffer)